# onclick from two elements not working with toggle properly

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want the div tag with `id="hidden-gift-order"` to be hidden when I click on the input and the div with `class="checkmark"`. When I click on the `input` it works but the `div` tag when clicked on doesn't work. Can someone explain why so?

```js
function Toggle_Visibility(p1) {
  document.getElementById(p1).classList.toggle("d-none");
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 mb-6">
  <label class="checkbox-container ps-4 cursor-pointer" id="orderasgift">
        <input id="giftbox" onclick="Toggle_Visibility('hidden-gift-order')" class="gift-order-checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <div class="checkmark" onclick="Toggle_Visibility('hidden-gift-order')"></div>
      </label>
</div>
<div class="d-none" id="hidden-gift-order">...</div>
```

UPDATE:
So, the div tag is a custom checkbox and I wanted to use that instead of the default one given to us. When I click on input and div inside the label, I want it to trigger Toggle_Visibility() and toggle the d-none class of the div#hidden-gift-order.
I am adding the CSS part of the code too!

PS: The Code snippet is not working so don't mind that, thanks!

CSS:

```
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    .checkbox-container .gift-order-checkbox {
        position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    
    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: var(--bs-white);
        border: solid var(--bs-primary);
    }
    
    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .checkbox-container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: var(--bs-light);
    }

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: var(--bs-white);
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.checkbox-container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.checkbox-container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid var(--bs-primary);
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    color: var(--bs-primary);
}
```

Comment: what you want exactly ? If you click div trigger Toggle_Visibility?

Comment: you should put the div tag outside the label tag

Comment: when you click on `div.checkmark`, will trigger a click event on input :

=> `Toggle_Visibility()` is called twice

Answer (score 0):

try to dont put input and div in label because when you click div the input is clicked too , i try this and its works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer>
      function Toggle_Visibility(p1) {
        document.getElementById(p1).classList.toggle("d-none");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-field col-lg-12 mb-6">
        <input
          id="giftbox"
          onclick="Toggle_Visibility('hidden-gift-order')"
          class="gift-order-checkbox"
          type="checkbox"
        />
        <div
          class="checkmark"
          onclick="Toggle_Visibility('hidden-gift-order')"
        >sdf
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none" id="hidden-gift-order">...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing is I am hiding the default checkbox and creating a separate one with the div, and so because of that it has been placed inside the label tag or it doesn't work properly.